# TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got set

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy

I use Scrapy to write spider,but i meet this error .Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class ZhihuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "zhihu"
    allowed_domains = ["www.zhihu.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        return [scrapy.Request('http://www.zhihu.com/#signin')]

    def parse(self, response):
        print response
```

the information of the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1183, in
_inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 389, in t
hrowExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", lin
e 37, in process_request
    response = yield method(request=request, spider=spider)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 587, in _
runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\robotstxt.py"
, line 45, in process_request_2
    to_native_str(self._useragent), request.url):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 127, in to_n
ative_str
    return to_bytes(text, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 117, in to_b
ytes
    'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got set
```

Comment: The Python error message says exactly where what went wrong. You'll need to share the **verbatim** Error.

Comment: i have shard  the verbatim error

Answer (score 1):

Your `allowed_domains` is not valid, like this

```
allowed_domains = ["zhihu.com"]
```

In scrapy.core.downloader.webclient.py, each URL will be parsed. Function `to_bytes` will check if it is `None`, otherwise it will raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score -1):

You can meet the error when you try to use wrong data type.
For example:

```
str = 15
print str.encode("ascii") # Error occurs

str = "15"
print str.encode("ascii") # Right code because encode function belongs to unicode string data type but not integer.
```

Comment: However,there is none code like this,why my code should get this error?